# PHP convert a number to the power of

Tags: php

I have a sql database with figures such as 100, 1000, 10,000 etc.

Using php, how can I convert these figures so they are a power of 10?

e.g. 
1,000 stored in database
Needs to be displayed as 10<sup>3</sup>

In case you are not aware of powers of 10, 10<sup>3</sup> = 10 × 10 × 10 (so 1000).

All figures in the database will be divisible by 10 and will have a power of 10. e.g. 10,000 (10<sup>4</sup>).

Thanks in advance for any help.

If possible, please include a basic example.

### Edit / Solution

Log10() is correct. So with my DB query I used:

```
10<sup>" . log10($row['number']) . "</sup>
```

### Secondary problem

If a number is not a power of e.g. if someone enters 0 (this is the only number that can be entered that will not be a power of), it displays "-INF". Other than using a php if statment e.g.

```
if $row['number'] == 0
```

is there a way to not display the INF?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [log10()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log10.php) function.

If you think mathematically, log base 10 of 100 gives the exponent 2.

```
echo log10(1000); // 3

echo log10(1000000); // 6
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use

`10<sup>" . log10($row['number']) . "</sup>'`

worked a treat

Comment: p.s. I have upvoted your answer but due to new/no rep it isn't showing.

Comment: When the power to 10 = 0 I get "-INF". Do you know a way to catch this and not display (or is it a case of writing a full php if statement)?

Comment: There is no power of 10 equal to 0, because 10**0 is equal to 1. Just check that that number is not 0 with something like this `$row["number"] === 0 ? "0" : log10($row["number"])`